# Blazegraph: How to LOAD gzip files?

Tags: sparql, blazegraph

I need to load gzip-ed Trig files into a Blazegraph instance and the problem is that Blazegraph apparently cannot handle gzip over its REST API.

I tried to load the data via SPARQL with `LOAD <file:///path/to/gzip/somerdf.ttl.gzip> INTO GRAPH <https://named.graph>` but I get an HTTP 500.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you not unzip them programatically (maybe with powershell if those languages support it) and just pass it the uncompressed file instead?

Comment: @easleyfixed thank you for your reply. The problem is that I get "HTTP 413 Content Too Large" without the gziping. I feel really stupid, it should be easy to do this and the gzip approach works with Fuseki and GraphDB.. :|

Comment: Oh shoot ... I see the issue.  Well if you can't use a zip format, and the normal file is too large, could you not split the data somehow and do it in 2 smaller chunks?  Then perhaps you could combine those two outcomes if it all needs to be in one thing.

Comment: I thought about chunking, but this is somewhat of a last resort since I don't know how the triplestore handles this and I need to target named graphs. I mean just randomly creating chunks would result in invalid RDF which the triplestore would reject, right?

Comment: Yeah I mean that is sort of the problem conceptually because yeah if it wasn't perfectly done somehow, it might not realize how to proced.   There is the other side of the coin though, not sure hows its done there, but if this was in Internet Information Systems, you could increase some of the timeouts to allow  more time for the data to be pooled, perhaps something exists like that with what you are using.

Comment: The only thing left to try would be "semantic chunking", i.e. dissecting the RDF sources into smaller *valid* RDF sources and ingesting those into the graph in sequence. This is a major pain however, especially since any REST interface and triplestore should support gzip/ingesting large-ish files out of box. Seriously how does Blazegraph even work out for anyone if it can't load larger sources?!?

Comment: before doing something different, I'd try to use the file extension `.gz` instead of `.gzip` - Blazegraph might check for this

Comment: other than that, is it necessary to use SPARQL `LOAD` instead of the Blazegraph bulk loader?